# updating my project to latest bootstrap and jquery

Tags: jquery, momentjs, bootstrap-5, updates

I want to update few technologies in my project like:-

- Jquery
- Bootstrap
- moment
- jquery ui
  to its current latest respective versions.

I am not able to figure out that which technology should I update first, As i had tried to update moment it gives error regarding date formats says
**TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '_longDateFormat')**

Also tried to update jQuery alone, at that case so many things breaks like:- Navbar notworking, dropdown scroll etc.

I want to update all the above technologies one by one, so what should i update first

Comment: It's likely they're all inter-related enough you'll have to upgrade them all together. (Particularly jQuery and jQuery UI.)

Comment: Is it possible that we first update Jquery and jquery ui? After that we update bootstrap

Comment: You probably shouldn't be using bootstrap *and* jquery-ui together as they have conflicts.  If you are, you might already have a bunch of css overrides to handle it.

Comment: You can upgrade bootstrap to latest at any time - the latest bootstrap doesn't use jquery, taking it out of the equation (for the bootstrap update at least).

Comment: Even the authors of [tag:moment.js] recommend that you don't use moment.js (as of 2020), so you should consider "upgrading" that first to *remove it completely*.

Comment: Then it depends on which version of jquery-ui you currently have - if it's quite old then, as per comment above, you'll need to do jquery and jquery-ui at the same time.